# Procedure created with compilation errors in oracle.?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, syntax-error

I wrote simple stored procedure in oracle. but its shows procedure created with compilation errors.

My code is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PRC_SELECT
AS
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM tb_name;
END;
/
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: `SHOW ERRORS`. could give you the errors. You must assign the selected rows into some record/variable

Comment: SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PRC_SELECT
  2  (old IN VARCHAR)
  3  AS
  4  BEGIN
  5  SELECT * FROM dds WHERE old=@old;
  6  END;
  7  /

Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.

Comment: Sorry, is this Oracle/MySQL ?

Comment: this is oracle 10g. if you r a genius in oracle means just write some sample procedure here

Comment: You need to do what OracleUser told you: run `show errors` after running the `create` statement.

Comment: @Sesuraj I am not a genius!! but can try hard for it if you provided more data on what you want!! :)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what did you expect your procedure to do?

Answer (score 2):

This is a very basic skeleton, for your requirement.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PRC_SELECT(p_OLD IN VARCHAR2)
AS
my_rec tb_name%rowtype;
BEGIN
SELECT * into my_rec  FROM tb_name WHERE old = p_OLD;
END;
/
```

`my_rec` will be created as a `PL/SQL` type whose structure would be table `tb_name`'s structure!

Answer (score 0):

a procedure cannot do a select * back to the screen.
you would have to bulk collect it into a collection and return it or open a cursor and return that.
a procedure is pl/sql, which doesn't directly write to the screen.
if you want it, you can use dbms_output.put_line to write each record.
you might also want to look into pipelined functions, which can be used in SQL later.
it depends what you're requirements are really.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to read all the rows in `tb_name` you could try:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PRC_SELECT
AS
BEGIN
  FOR aRow IN (SELECT * FROM tb_name)
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Retrieved ' || aRow.SOME_FIELD);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Note that this may produce a lot of output if there are many rows in `tb_name`.

Share and enjoy.